# How to do Authentication and Crud operations using Ionic 4, mysql and Angular 7?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework

I am beginner in ionic 4 and Angular and unable to recognize that how i can connect Mysql data base for it??

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple service to store data (make simple service)
then pass it using ionic 
**[check this for HTTP call](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http)**

[original link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http)

```
 this.http.get('http://your_address', {}, {})
      .then(data => {

        console.log(yourdata.status);
        console.log(yourdata.data); // data received by server
        console.log(yourdata.headers);

      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

      });
```

[check this for creating Api](https://nomadphp.com/blog/69/create-simple-restful-apis-using-php-mysql)